# Concurrent modification of TreeMap in Java

Tags: java, c++, iterator

I have following container in C++:

```
std::unordered_map<keyType, std::map<otherKeyType, keyValue>::iterator> Container;
```

Somewhere in my code I use this container to quickly access elements in std::map container, and I can concurrently modify this map without any problems and always my iterators are valid (I remove elements from this map only in one place).

I want to reproduce this behaviour in Java, but I know that Java doesn't have something like that in standard TreeMap container.

Is there any way to save a "fast path" to some element in TreeMap, which would skip logarithmic (in time) search in this TreeMap? Should I somehow use references and create my own container, or is there some sort or "magical container" that will fit my needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent to a `std::unordered_map` in Java is a `HashMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap`, which have expected constant-time lookups.  A `TreeMap` is an ordered map

If you need an ordered map, then a [splay tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) might suit your needs - the more frequently accessed objects in a splay tree will gravitate towards the top, which reduces their lookup time.  There are several Java implementations available via google.  Another option is to maintain a hashmap cache of the last K elements that you've accessed from the treemap.

Comment: Yes, I know that. The thing is, that this "inside map" has to be ordered map. As far as I know, HashMaps are not ordered.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, but I have one more question. Is it possible to implement ordered map and it's iterators from C++ in Java using references, or is it possible only with pointers (and that's why I can do it in C++, but not in Java)?

Comment: @Glibnes Most data structures / algorithms that use C++ pointers directly translate into analogous data structures / algorithms that use Java references - the exception is if you're doing something like pointer arithmetic that has no analogue in Java