# Removing instance in two-dimensional TreeMap in JAVA

Tags: java, treemap

Hi I'm doing homework for my school and am trying to remove instance from two-dimensional `TreeMap<String, TreeMap<Date, Integer>` and keep it the same structure

my function that is supposed to do that :

```
public void vyhodExpirovane(){
    Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    TreeMap<Date, Integer> produkt;
    System.out.println(now);
    for (String name: obsah.keySet()){
        produkt = obsah.get(name);
        System.out.print(name + " pocet roznych" + produkt.size() + " datum");
        for (Date d: produkt.keySet()){
            System.out.println( d + " pocet:" + produkt.get(d));
            if (d.before(now)) {
                obsah.get(name).remove(d);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my map looks like this

```
<cheese , <Mar 10 10:58:02 CET 2015, 1>>
<apple , <Mar 10 10:58:02 CET 2015, 1> <Mar 10 11:58:02 CET 2015, 2>>
```

when the remove from my function removes first occurance of apple and is supposed to go to second it crashes with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
at Chladnicka.vyhodExpirovane(Chladnicka.java:126)
at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:46)
```

which is on the inner for loop (for (Date d: produkt.keySet()))

any idea why is it crashing?

Comment: It is crushing because for inside iterator it is allowed to use `Iterator#remove()` only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concurent modification of TreeMap in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577992/concurent-modification-of-treemap-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for (Date d: produkt.keySet()){
        System.out.println( d + " pocet:" + produkt.get(d));
        if (d.before(now)) {
            obsah.get(name).remove(d);
        }
    }
```

You cannot remove an element from a collection while iterating it, this is causing the error.

---

You should use the fact that you have `TreeMap`, that maintains order of the elements, so your items are already sorted according to `Date`!

You can use this fact to simply your code and use the [`tailMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#tailMap(K)) functionality  and get a submap that include only keys with higher dates already.

This can be done instead of modifying your existing map - create a new one using the mentioned method, and put it in the original tree.

```
 obsah.put(name, obsah.get(name).tailMap(now))
```

Note that modifying a *value* (of the outer map) while iterating does not cause this exception.

Comment: but the tailMap() returns sortedMap instead of TreeMap... can i retype it or how should i change the type?

Comment: @joasisk Do you actually care if it is a TreeMap or a SortedMap? If you don't - the more generic SortedMap is preferred to be the type anyway.

Comment: It has to be TreeMap since I have to put it back in predefined structure (see above)

Comment: @joasisk One simple solution is to use `new TreeMap<>(obsah.get(name).tailMap(now));`, using the [`TreeMap(Map)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Map)) constructor I believe the actual type returned is a TreeMap, but I am not sure and it is not guaranteed, so better safe than sorry

Comment: @joasisk `SortedMap` is an interface, it's not a concrete implementation, I have no idea what implementation it returns, but as I offered - there is an alternative of just using the constructor as described. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

It is crashing because you try to remove an element while you implicitly iterating your tree map (as it affects the internal iteration index). You should keep the keys you want to remove in a temporary data structure and remove the keys after iterating the tree map.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Iterator` instead of inner loop:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<Date, Integer>> i = produkt.entrySet().iterator();
Map.Entry<Date, Integer> e;
while (i.hasNext() && (e = i.next()) != null) {
    if (e.getKey().before(now)) {
         i.remove();
    }
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#entrySet%28%29